# Make: Target selection

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to make. I tried running sample make as shown below.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
OBJ = hellofunc.o hellomake.o
SRC = hellofunc.c hellomake.c
DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $@)) -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS) $<

test:
        @echo "inside test target"

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $^


include $(DEPS)
```

Output :

```
inside test target
```

As per make manual, it is saying that *By default, make starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’)*. So in this case first target is `%.o: %c`, right? Why it is not running that rule first? I don't have object files in my directory. make has to check for the absence of object files and try to build with C files using first rule, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a 'make target'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270643/what-is-a-make-target)

Comment: A pattern rule doesn't define a target.  Just like a template doesn't define a class or a document (depending on what kind of template you are thinking of).  A pattern rule says "if you don't have a recipe to build a given target which matches this pattern, here's a way to do it".  Since it doesn't refer to a specific target it cannot be used to choose the specific target which is the default goal for make.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html), not a target. It does not specify a specific target file name, just a rule for how to produce an `*.o` file (to use shell wildcard notation) if there should ever be a circumstance in which you need to do that.

You should probably move the `hellomake` rule so it comes before `test` (and probably before the pattern rule, too, for human legibility).

If you want all those `$(CC)` options to be applied to all `*.c` files, just add them to `CFLAGS`. Then there is no need really to override `make`'s built-in pattern rule.